# how can use limit offset with where clause in apache drill?

Tags: apache-drill

I am working on apache drill query and i want to use limit and offset in my query.

query :-

```
SELECT  * FROM dfs.`C:\\EMPLOYEES.csv` LIMIT 20 OFFSET 5 ROWS
```

Above mention query were executing and giving correct result.
But i want to use limit and offset with where clause.

```
SELECT  * FROM dfs.`C:\\EMPLOYEES.csv` WHERE COLUMN[0] ='1' LIMIT 20 OFFSET 5 ROWS
```

But this query is giving 0 result.

Please suggest how can i use limit offset with where clause inapache drill.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your data and filter condition, maybe nothing is returned since you don't have enough data matching the filter, limit and offset works perfectly fine with where clause.

Example:

Assume we have the following data:

```
apache drill> select * from dfs.tmp.`data.csv`;
+-----------+
|  columns  |
+-----------+
| ["1","a"] |
| ["2","b"] |
| ["1","c"] |
| ["2","d"] |
| ["1","f"] |
| ["2","g"] |
| ["1","h"] |
| ["1","q"] |
| ["1","w"] |
| ["1","y"] |
| ["1","t"] |
+-----------+
```

First filter is applied:

```
apache drill> select * from dfs.tmp.`data.csv` where columns[0] = '1';
+-----------+
|  columns  |
+-----------+
| ["1","a"] |
| ["1","c"] |
| ["1","f"] |
| ["1","h"] |
| ["1","q"] |
| ["1","w"] |
| ["1","y"] |
| ["1","t"] |
+-----------+
```

Then offset is applied:

```
apache drill> select * from dfs.tmp.`data.csv` where columns[0] = '1' offset 5;
+-----------+
|  columns  |
+-----------+
| ["1","w"] |
| ["1","y"] |
| ["1","t"] |
+-----------+
```

And only then limit:

```
apache drill> select * from dfs.tmp.`data.csv` where columns[0] = '1' limit 2 offset 5;
+-----------+
|  columns  |
+-----------+
| ["1","w"] |
| ["1","y"] |
+-----------+
```